# Draw a line on drag between two raphael objects

Tags: jquery, raphael

I have tried to draw a line connectors between two Raphael objects, but I can't do this.

I tried jsPlumb but it work only on div tag . I want to draw endpoint on raphael rectangle object. I have already tried this.

My code below that I used jsplumb with Raphael object:

```
$("#btnAI, #btnDI").live("click", function() {

        if(this.id == "btnAI")
            text = "AI";
        else
            text = "DI";

        var Execount = "#" + (++ecount);
        var SetAI = paper.set().draggable.enable();
        // create a set to store AI

        var outerRect = getRectangle(paper, 30, 40, 120, 120, "white", "Gray", 5);
        // outer Rectangle
        SetAI.push(outerRect);

        var InnerRect = getRectangle(paper, 40, 50, 100, 100, "#5a5a5a", "Gray", 5);
        // inner Rectangle
        SetAI.push(InnerRect);

        SetAI.push(GetText(paper, 90, 70, text + uniqueId("AI")));
        // text to display which contact

        SetAI.push(GetText(paper, 110, 130, Execount));
        // text for unique id

        SetAI.push(GetLine(paper, 40, 80, 100, 0));
        //upper line

        SetAI.push(GetLine(paper, 40, 120, 100, 0));
        //lower line

        SetAI.push(getRectangle(paper, 99, 90, 41, 20, null, "#FFF", 0));
        //rect to display o/p value

        SetAI.push(getRectangle(paper, 40, 85, 48, 30, null, "#FFF", 0));
        //rect to display o/p value

        jsPlumb.setMouseEventsEnabled(true);
                jsPlumb.setRenderMode();
                jsPlumb.Defaults.Container = 'canvasdiv';
                jsPlumb.Defaults.Overlays = [["Arrow", {
                            location : 0.9
                        }], ["Label", {
                            location : 0.1,
                            label : function(label) {
                                return label.connection.labelText || "";
                            },
                            cssClass : "aLabel"
                        }]];
                outerRect.node.setAttribute("class","jsclass");
                var sourceEndpoint = {
                        endpoint : "Rectangle",
                        paintStyle : {
                            fillStyle : "red",
                            width:20,
                            height:15
                        },
                        isSource : true,
                        connector : ["Flowchart", {
                            stub : 40
                        }],
                        connectorStyle : {
                        lineWidth : 3,
                        joinstyle : "round",
                        strokeStyle :"Green",
                    },
                        connectorHoverStyle :{
                        lineWidth : 3,
                        strokeStyle : "#2e2aF8"
                    },
                        dropOptions : {
                            hoverClass : "hover",
                            activeClass : "active",
                            zIndex:1000
                        },
                }

                var targetEndpoint = {
                        endpoint : "Rectangle",
                        paintStyle : {
                            fillStyle : "green",
                            width:20,
                            height:15
                        },
                        isTarget : true,
                        connector : ["Flowchart", {
                            stub : 40
                        }],
                        connectorStyle : {
                        strokeStyle : "#FF3333",
                        lineWidth : 2
                    },
                    dropOptions : {
                            hoverClass : "hover",
                            activeClass : "active"
                        },
                }

                jsPlumb.addEndpoint(outerRect.node, {anchor : "BottomCenter"}, sourceEndpoint);
                //jsPlumb.addEndpoint(outerRect.node, {anchor : "RightMiddle"}, targetEndpoint);
                jsPlumb.draggable($(".jsclass"));
```

Please help out for this.

Comment: Harshal, what you're describing should be reasonably easy to accomplish.  But before anyone ventures any code, it might be a good idea for you to point out an example or an illustration of exactly what you have in mind.  What sorts of raphael objects?  What sort of connectors, and with what functionality?  More detail please.

Comment: We won't write your code for you, which is why you're getting downvotes.  Try it yourself, and then show us what you did if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A good jQuery line drawing program is [jsPlumb](http://jsplumb.org).

Comment: I tried jsPlumb but it work only on div tag . I want to draw endpoint on raphael rectangle object. How can i do this. i have already tried this.